# Determine the fourier cosine series of $f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Determine the fourier cosine series of the triangular wave formed by extending the function $f(x)$as a periodic function of period $2$
>   $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> 1+x,&-1\leq x \leq 0\\
> 1-x, & \phantom{-}0\leq x \leq 1 
> \end{cases}
> $$

Here is what I have came up with but I am not sure if I am correct. Is my calculation for $a_n$ correct? Do I need to calculate $a_0$ also?

$L$ is the half period of the extended periodic function. In our case one period is given on $[-1,1]$, so the period is $2$ and $L = 1 $

I used the following half range formulas, is this correct? I only calculated one but doubled it.

$$a_n = \frac{2}{L} \int^{L}_0(1-x)\cos \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) dx= 2\int_0^1(1-x)\cos (n\pi x) dx $$

Through a series of integration I have determined and I checked it via a online calculator.

$$a_n = \frac{-2(-1)^n}{\pi ^2 n^2} + \frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compress your last formula using that
$$
1-(-1)^n=\begin{cases}
2&n\text{ odd}\\
0&n\text{ even}
\end{cases}
$$
thus
$$
a_{2n+1}=\frac{4}{\pi^2(2n+1)^2},
$$
all other coefficients zero. Except for $a_0$, where obviously this formula does not work.

Let's see what your coefficients give, set
$$
f(n,x)=4\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\cos(\pi (2k+1)x)}{\pi^2(2k+1)^2}
$$
and graph some examples with low number $n$ of terms:

```
gnuplot> c(n,x) = 4*cos((2*n+1)*pi*x)/((2*n+1)*pi)**2
gnuplot> f(n,x) = (n<0)?0:c(n,x)+f(n-1,x)
gnuplot> pl [-1.5:2.5] f(1,x), f(3,x), f(5,x) lw 2
```

[image]

which is looking good except for the missing constant term.

Comment: thanks for your very detailed answer! I appreciate it very much. I just quickly calculated $$a_0 = \int_{-1}^0(1+x)dx+\int^{1}_0(1-x)dx = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} =  1$$

Therefore the final solution would be,

$$f(x) = 1 + \sum^{\infty} _ {n=1} -\frac{4}{\pi^2(2n+1)^2}$$

Should the $a_0$ in the solution be $1$ or $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Check again the formula for $a_0$, it has a different coefficient in front of the integral than the other Fourier coefficients. Visibly, shifting the graph up by $0.5$ will give the graph for the required function.

Comment: then how do I calculate $a_0?$ once I have this done my solution will be complete

Comment: That depends on your Fourer/cosine series. Some chose $f(x)=\frac{a_0}2+a_1\cos(\pi x/L)+...$ where your formula above is right, others prefer $f(x)=a_0+a_1\cos(\pi /L)+...$ where the factor $\frac12$ is shifted to the integral formula.

Comment: okay I will use 

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \sum^{\infty} _ {n=1} -\frac{4}{\pi^2(2n+1)^2}$$

Comment: Sorry about the minus sign, it was not in the formulas for the graph, don't know how it arrived in the other formulas.

Comment: okay so take that minus sign out then my answer will be complete, thanks!

Comment: should the final answer with the summation include $cos(nx)$ since it is the $a_n$ term?

Comment: It better be $\cos(\pi(2n+1)x)$ as the coefficients are $a_{2n+1}$ and the function is $2$-periodic.